# convert ipynb notebook to org and execute in emacs

Tags: emacs, jupyter, org-mode

I've seen some applauses for org-babel in place of jupyter (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16842786) and trying out what it is about.

I'd like to convert *.ipynb file to *.org file and the execute each source block in org mode as we would do in jupyter notebook.

(I tried `ein` couple of days, but it seems unstable)

I've succeeded converting file formats as illustrated in https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7lcgkz/import_a_jupyter_notebook_to_an_orgmode_file/

However I'm having hard time executing code blocks because variables are not shared among code blocks.

Can I use `PROPERTIES:` or similar method to run them in the same context? 
Can I use ipython?

I failed to google how to use org mode for ipynb file (as I try to do).
Would like to know if someone shares a work process of doing it

Answer (score 1):

If variables are not shared between code blocks it might be due to the lack of `:session` argument otherwise each code block is run in standalone mode. For instance, the second block should print `i`

```
#+begin_src python :session my_session
i = 0
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :session my_session :results output
print(i)
#+end_src
```

whereas this one should raised a `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` error

```
#+begin_src python :results output
print(i)
#+end_src
```